# Upload a pdf document to Google docs using APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, api, google-drive

Trying to load pdf document to Google Docs, by using the Google API . so the issue I am facing that the pdf file was uploaded on docs but when we download it and open it shows an error:-Failed to load PDF document.

```
 if(fileTypeValue=='PDFFile'){
                 
                       
  body = delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + '{ "title" : "' + templateName + '",' + ' "mimeType" : "' +'application/pdf' + '",' + '"parents":[{"id":"'+DriveFolderId1+'"}]}' + delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + 'text/html' + '\r\n' + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' + bodyEncoded + closedelim;                
                }
             
                endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart';
          
                valueOfFile = getdriveAPIresponse('POST',body, endpoint);
                filename = '';
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Google it : https://initaura.com/file-upload/#:~:text=Create%20a%20button%20%E2%80%9CUpload%20File,method%20from%20your%20controller%20class.

OR 

https://blog.webnersolutions.com/salesforce-google-drive-integration-upload-files-from-salesforce-to-google-drive/

Comment: Hi Nagendra, I already refer to this link.

Comment: Ok, the error message suggests that your file got corrupted while getting transferred to google drive. So until we get to see what file are you trying to transfer it would be difficult. Some files while getting converted into base64 have issues in their padding. So you can use this class to convert the files to base64 format (which sends a multipart request to the external api). https://github.com/MetaMind/apex-utils/blob/master/HttpFormBuilder.apex

Comment: If the file is corrupted it should not load in google drive as well but I am able to see content there

Comment: As written by you in your question the file gets uploaded fine, but when you download and try to see the contents of the file you get an error "failed to load pdf document". This error message suggests that there was some corrupted characters in the file while converting it to base64. I suggest you try above class to convert your file to base64 and try.